# Trying to implement an object-oriented design model for a simple navbar using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Greetings fellow Earthicans,

The following code is used on my website: [brianjenkins94.me](http://brianjenkins94.me/) in order to handle baseline navigation functionality and while it was working previously I decided to leverage the class-based approach provided by the [TypeScript Language](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) in order to structure my code in a more readable fashion. In doing so I seem to have broken the functionality and now all #nav.on("click") events trigger the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeClass' of undefined` on Line 54 (see comment in code).

If anyone could identify why this code is nonfunctional or perhaps provide some insight as to whether there is a better way of going about doing this, (**I'm really interested in proper design and right practice,** *the bug is just a convenient excuse to make a post and get input*) it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks ahead of time,

Brian

---

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
"use strict";

class Main {

  //private SERVERNAME: string = "http://brianjenkins94.me/";
  //private DOCUMENTROOT: string = "https://rawgit.com/brianjenkins94/local.blog.com/master/"

  public init(): void {
    $(function(): void {
      var Nav: Navigation = new Navigation($("body"), $("#nav"), $("a[href=\"#nav\"]"));
      Nav.init();

    });
  }
}

class Navigation {
  private body: JQuery;
  private nav: JQuery;
  private navToggle: JQuery;
  private navClose: JQuery = $("<a></a>");

  constructor(bodyInit: JQuery, navInit: JQuery, navToggleInit: JQuery) {
    this.body = bodyInit;
    this.nav = navInit;
    this.navToggle = navToggleInit;
    // Create navClose element
    this.navClose.attr({
      href: "#",
      tabIndex: 0
    });
    (this.navClose).addClass("close");
    (this.nav).append(this.navClose);
  };

  public init(): void {
    this.disablePropogation();
    this.clickListener(this.body);
    this.clickListener(this.navToggle);
    this.clickListener(this.navClose);
    this.clickListener(this.nav);
    this.keyCodeListener();

  }

  private disablePropogation(): void {
    (this.nav).on("click touchend", function(event: Event): void {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  }

  private clickListener(target: JQuery): void {
    (target).on("click touchend", function(): void {
      if (!(target === (this.body))) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        if (target === this.navToggle) {
          (this.nav).toggleClass("visible");
          return;
        }
      }
      (this.nav).removeClass("visible"); // They call me, line 54
    });
  }

  private keyCodeListener(): void {
    $(window).on("keydown", function(event: JQueryKeyEventObject): void {
      if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        (this.nav).removeClass("visible");
      }
    });
  }

}

var main: Main = new Main();
main.init();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is of the wrong type (window) and not the instance of the class. The best way to fix It is by using an Arrow function to capture the `this` reference like below:

```
private clickListener(target: JQuery): void {
    (target).on("click touchend", () => {
      if (!(target === (this.body))) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        if (target === this.navToggle) {
          (this.nav).toggleClass("visible");
          return;
        }
      }
      (this.nav).removeClass("visible"); // They call me, line 54
    });
}
```

Check out the generated code on what it actually does. If you also want to use `this` provided by jQuery (the element in this case) you can also do

```
var that = this;
```

Right above the `on` call and use `that` for the class and `this` for your jQuery target. This is similar to what the arrow function generates but that generates `_this` instead of "that".

**edit** if you need to keep TSLint happy you should probably do `() :void => {` in the arrow function

Comment: That seems to have really aggravated TSLint: [Image](http://i.imgur.com/z2cY1gk.png) but I'm still looking into it.

Comment: Oops, sorry updated my post the `void` should not be there